# Regex and verbose in python 3

Tags: python, regex

I'm reading [Dive into Python 3](http://getpython3.com/diveintopython3/regular-expressions.html) about regular expressions and specifically using re.VERBOSE. I tried searching for a string, but it always returns "None". For example:

```
import re
pattern = '''
testing
'''

print(re.search(pattern, 'test', re.VERBOSE))
```

I had thought that this should return something other than None because the pattern of characters "test" exists in "testing". I had also thought that if it had been something like:

```
pattern = '''
^testing$
'''
```

Then it makes sense that I would get a return value of None if I searched for the same string. However, regardless, I always seem to get a return value of None. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have your patterns and text-to-search mixed up.

You are looking for `testing` in text `test`, and the latter is not nearly long enough. :-)

If you reversed the two (pattern `test`, text `testing`) things work:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = '''
... test
... '''
>>> print(re.search(pattern, 'testing', re.VERBOSE))
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1062f4c60>
```